# Error persisting Doctrine 2 ODM document to Mongo (GridFS)

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, gridfs, doctrine-odm

I am trying to persist a document via Doctrine ODM in Symfony2 to MongoDB (GridFS), but when I try to persist the document, I receive this error,

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\MongoDB\GridFSFile::setMongoGridFSFile() must be an instance of MongoGridFSFile, null given, called in /path/to/project/vendor/doctrine/mongodb/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/GridFS.php on line 97 and defined in /path/to/project/vendor/doctrine/mongodb/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/GridFSFile.php on line 154
```

The weird bit, is that when I then go and check MongoDB, the file is there, and I am able to download it.

I've checked permissions on the file, and that isn't the issue.

Entity:

```
namespace Path\Here\SomeBundle\Document;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;


/**
 * @ODM\Document(db="files_and_stuff",collection="fs",slaveOkay=true)
 */

class UploadFile
{
    /**
     * @ODM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /** @ODM\File */
    private $file;

    /** @ODM\String */
    private $filename;

    /** @ODM\String */
    private $mimeType;

    /** @ODM\Date */
    private $uploadDate;

    /** @ODM\Int */
    private $length;

    /** @ODM\Int */
    private $chunkSize;

    /** @ODM\String */
    private $md5;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function setFile($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function getFilename()
    {
        return $this->filename;
    }

    public function setFilename($filename)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }

    public function getMimeType()
    {
        return $this->mimeType;
    }

    public function setMimeType($mimeType)
    {
        $this->mimeType = $mimeType;
    }

    public function getChunkSize()
    {
        return $this->chunkSize;
    }

    public function getLength()
    {
        return $this->length;
    }

    public function getMd5()
    {
        return $this->md5;
    }

    public function getUploadDate()
    {
        return $this->uploadDate;
    }

}
```

Manager method:

```
public function uploadDocument() {

    $fileName = uniqid();

    $tmpPath = "/tmp/" . $fileName;
    imagepng($image, $tmpPath, 0);

    $UploadFile = new UploadFile();
    $UploadFile->setFilename($fileName);
    $UploadFile->setMimeType('image/png');
    $UploadFile->setFile($tmpPath);

    $this->dm->persist($UploadFile);
    $this->dm->flush();

    unlink($tmpPath);

    return $UploadFile;

}
```

Comment: I don't have a solution at the moment, but this question was referenced in https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/issues/182 -- so I wanted to link back for context in case a solution pops up after looking into that issue.